# Java Nodes how to store nodes as pairs of data

Tags: java, nodes, graph-theory

I want to make a program where you can make nodes and connect them, I wanna make Graphical interface so you can see the graphs. My problem is I need to store the edges in between nodes(vertices) some people at my university told me to use maps?

I've tried to store the nodes with a map structure and making my own pair class:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Node extends Main {
    public String data;
    int ID;
    Boolean IsConnected = false;

    public Node(String data, int ID, int Connection ) {
        this.data = data;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void Connect(Node N1, Node N2) {
    }

    public boolean IsConnected(Node N1, Node N2) {
        if (map.containsValue(N1) && map.containsKey(N2)) {
            System.out.println("connected");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("not connected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what problem you have with your code (nor shown all the relevant parts). And you should have asked those "some people" what they meant when they told you to use maps

Comment: Edge can be stored as a `Set<Node>` attribute in the node class. You could use a `Map<Node, Set<Node>>`, but it's effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This addresses one way to logically represent edges of a graph. It does not address how to represent a graph visually.

I'm going to assume the number of nodes needed will be known. If that is not the case, this answer will need to be changed.

A common way to represent edges of a graph is to use an adjacency matrix. Given `n` Nodes, the simplest adjacency matrix for a directed graph is an 2D array of `boolean`:

```
 boolean [][] adjacent = new boolean [n][n];
```

This requires each `Node` to be associated with an index. One way to do that is to use an array:

```
 Node [] myNodes = new node [n];
```

Then, finding out if there is an edge between two nodes is simple:

```
 public boolean areConnected (int a, int b) { 
    return adjacent [a][b];
 }
```

And, they are easy to connect:

```
  public void Connect (int from, int to) { 
       adjacent [from][to] = true;
  }
```

If you need to search to find the index of a Node, you can add this code:

```
 public int indexOf (Node node) { 
     int index = -1;
     for (int i = 0; i < myNodes.length; ++i) {
        if (node.equals (myNode [i]) { 
           index = i;
           break;
        }
     }
  }

  public boolean areConnected (Node a, Node b) { 
      int locA = indexOf (a);
      int locB = indexOf (b);
      if (locA < 0 || locB < 0) { 
         return false;
      }
      return areConnected (locA, locB);
  }
```

**NOTE:** Please seriously consider overriding `equals (Object other)` and `hashCode()` methods. Whether you use an adjacency matrix as described here, or a `Collection`, the default `.equals (Object other)` will be equivalent to `this == other`. That is, it will test if they refer to the same Object.  If you want to know if the contents of `Node` Objects are the same, you need to override `equals`. If you override `equals`, you should also override `hashCode()`.

**Note:** You will want to decide how to guard against the possibility that an invalid index or node will be passed to `areConnected` or `Connect`. You might, for example, want to throw an exception.

**Note:** This assumes a directed graph.

**Comment:** The beginning of this answer has this statement: *"I'm going to assume the number of nodes needed will be known early."* "Early" means "before the matrix is constructed". One way to represent an adjacency matrix in which the number of nodes is flexible is to use a `List<List<Boolean>>`. That can represent a 2D `List`.

An adjacency matrix is not restricted to `boolean`. For example, if each `Node` represented a city, the adjacency matrix might be an `int [][]` , where each entry represents the number of highway miles between cities. A `double` might represent the geographic distance. A `BigDecimal [][]` could represent the price of airfare between the cities. It could be an array of Objects of a class you create.